# What is the technology behind port numbers?

Tags: http, networking, ftp, webserver, port

I know that port numbers are used for identifying different processes running on a server, so that multiple processes can use the same networking resources. But how does it work internally?

For example, if a request to a website `http://www.my-awesome-website.com:80` reaches a server, how does the server know that there is a web server running on port 80? I mean, what does the request pipeline look like between getting the request to finding out that a web server is running on port 80 and forwarding the request to the web server?

Comment: @ the developer level the technology is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

but for your example, it is any piece of software that implements listener behavior. For the web site, its the web server (iis or apache). They listen on the ports for hello messages that start the exchange of data

So your url tells internet explorer to call the server at the url on port 80. the server is there listening for internet explorers all over the world to come say hello and ask for a page

Comment: oh and processids are used for identifying processes running on a server. 

ports are like docks for transported data to land. think of incoming data like tie fighters. ports are the docking bays in the death star

Comment: The 'technology' is a data structure in the TCP part of the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening a socket(which is like an open file but used for network communications), the user of the socket may use it directly with an ephemeral port(selected by the OS), which is typical if the application is a client application.

What server processes do is to call the `bind()` socket API call to set a port for the socket, and then call `listen()` in case of a TCP socket to start listening for incoming connection requests.

Because of the `bind()` call the OS will know that this particular socket is the one receiving the data sent to the particular port number.

The packets sent over the network contain the source and destination IP addresses as well as the source and destination ports:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/exploring-the-anatomy-of-a-data-packet/

So the OS has a data structure with open sockets listed by their port numbers and it will pass the received data to the correct socket's input buffer. Sent data will be marked by the port number of the sending socket.

Comment: The packet headers contain the layer-3 (in this case IP) addresses, but it is the packet payload (the layer-4 segments) which contain the port numbers (layer-4 addresses) in the layer-4 segment headers.

Comment: @Sami Sallinen @Ron Maupin So does that mean that the technology I'm after is implemented in the following way: Request hits a server -> Transport layer of TCP model strips down the request to find the port  -> Server checks its data structure to find the socket listed(by `bind()`) for the port number -> Passes the request to the `listen()` method of the socket -> Request is then handled by the process. Is this correct?

Comment: listen() is just used to tell the OS that the socket is listening for connections (is a server socket) for both server and client socket the OS just puts the received data to the receive buffer of the socket. The application will read it using read(). The OS also wakes up any thread that might be in a select() call for the socket to tell the application that there is new data to be read.

Comment: Simplified: request hits a server, layer-2 frame header is examined to see which layer-3 protocol should receive the packet, packet is passed up the stack, layer-3 header is examined to see which layer-4 protocol should receive the segment, the segment is passed up the stack, the layer-4 segment header is examined to see which port (application) should receive the resulting datagram, the datagram is passed to the application.

Answer (score 2):

Port numbers are merely addresses for some transport-layer protocols, such as TCP and UDP, in the same way that IP addresses are for layer-3 protocols, and MAC addresses are for layer-2 protocols. Not all transport-layer protocols use ports, and each transport-layer protocol independently maintains its ports so that TCP port 80 is not the same as UDP port 80, and each can be used simultaneously by different applications.

Layer-2 addresses are only relevant to the LAN links, layer-3 addresses are only relevant host-to-host over the layer-3 network, and layer-4 addresses are relevant application-to-application.

IANA registers ports and maintains the official registry list at [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

From [RFC 793, TRANSMISSION CONTROL PROTOCOL](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> Multiplexing:

> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
> communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
> addresses or ports within each host.  Concatenated with the network
> and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms
> a socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection.
> That is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple
> connections.
>
> The binding of ports to processes is handled independently by each
> Host.  However, it proves useful to attach frequently used processes
> (e.g., a "logger" or timesharing service) to fixed sockets which are
> made known to the public.  These services can then be accessed
> through the known addresses.  Establishing and learning the port
> addresses of other processes may involve more dynamic mechanisms.
>
> Connections:
>
> The reliability and flow control mechanisms described above require
> that TCPs initialize and maintain certain status information for
> each data stream.  The combination of this information, including
> sockets, sequence numbers, and window sizes, is called a connection.
> Each connection is uniquely specified by a pair of sockets
> identifying its two sides.
>
> When two processes wish to communicate, their TCP's must first
> establish a connection (initialize the status information on each
> side).  When their communication is complete, the connection is
> terminated or closed to free the resources for other uses.
>
> Since connections must be established between unreliable hosts and
> over the unreliable internet communication system, a handshake
> mechanism with clock-based sequence numbers is used to avoid
> erroneous initialization of connections.